# Microsoft Edge, Always Prompt Credential for Saveral User When Open Sharepoint O365

Tags: configuration, active-directory, registry, microsoft-edge, sharepoint-online

i have finished develop a portal site with sharepoint online (O365), and i facing a weird issue.

the issue is when user open the portal site via Microsoft Edge always prompt credential, and there only occoured for  several users. but for another user just input credential at first time.

so we just need to let the credential entered at a first time. for next time,  then users does not need to enter the credential again.

i have tried to compare the configuration of microsoft edge, but not successfully.

please if you some clue, please help me. thanks

note : for default of home page of Microsoft edge alreadt setted up by the Active Directory server.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using **MS Edge Chromium browser** (Correct me if you are using the **Edge legacy** browser).

I suggest you paste `edge://settings/passwords` in the address bar and press the **Enter** key.

Check and make sure that **Sign in automatically** option is enabled. if it is disabled then Edge browser every time asks you for permission before signing in to the site.

[image]

Comment: all configuration like you said.. Sign in Automatically is turn on.
but microsoft edge alway prompt the credential

Comment: Please inform us of the version of the Edge browser where this issue occurs? Make sure that users are accessing the site in normal mode(not in private mode). If possible, try to reset the Edge browser. Please check whether any sign-in related policy is set from the Active Directory server or not?

Comment: we are using microsoft edge Version 88.0.705.50 (Official build) (64-bit)

Comment: Did you try to reset the Edge browser? If not, please try to test it and let us know about the results.

Comment: You can try to test and let us know about the test results.